# Is there a way to avoid using the full package name in xml with custom Views (Android)?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to do something like

```
<TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/settings_title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/settings />
```

instead of

```
<com.my.really.super.long.package.name.that.wont.autocomplete.TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/settings_title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/settings />
```

I figure I could just put custom Views in the (default) package, but that seems like a bad idea. (EDIT: And upon testing this, it doesn't work anyway) Is there a "good" way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

No, AFAIK you will have to go with the full name.

Comment: You were first, so if this is indeed the answer, I will mark it as such. :)

Comment: The only shortcut you're going to get is if you want to shorten the namespace for custom attributes by using xmlns:custom (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

Comment: @Error454, thanks! I am indeed using that technique for custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutInflater.setFactory(LayoutInflater.Factory) allows you to specify an object that performs custom view object creation given the tag name at run time.  This could be used to achieve what you want to do.  I'd call getFactory() first to retrieve the existing default factory object and use that for any view names that are not your custom views.